# Nokogiri how do I get this value out

Tags: ruby, parsing, nokogiri

I have this nokogiri object:

```
element.first
=> #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fc0cf8ac4b8 name="a" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fc0cf8ac454 name="class" value="fl">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fc0cf8ac42c name="id" value="flag16">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fc0cf8ac418 name="href" value="/flag/?flagCode=16&postingID=2884068312">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fc0cf8ac404 name="title" value="Wrong category, wrong site, discusses another post, or otherwise misplaced">] children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fc0cf8ab6bc "\n\t\t\t\tmiscategorized">]>
```

I need to get the number 2884068312 out from the `postingID` value.

Any idea how to achieve this?

```
element.first.value
NameError: undefined local variable or method `value' for main:Object
    from (irb):138
1.9.2-p290 :139 > element.first[:value]
 => nil 
1.9.2-p290 :140 > element.first["value"]
 => nil
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number is part of the `href` attribute, so try:

```
element.first['href']
```

The method [`[]`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-5B-5D) gets the text value of an attribute of a node.

That should give you the string `"/flag/?flagCode=16&postingID=2884068312"`. You can then use a regex to get the number, something like `/ID=(\d+)/` should work.

So putting it together:

```
element.first['href'][/ID=(\d+)/, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want element['href'] which will pull out: '/flag/?flagCode=16&postingID=2884068312'. Then you can take that value and run it through a regex to grab your number like:

```
postingID=(\d+)
```